# C# LINQ Lambda Expression for Inner Join Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am new to `LINQ` and **Lambda** and trying to do something like this query:

```
 SELECT p.*,o.QTYSUM FROM Database1..Table1 p 
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ISNULL(Sum(i.QTY),0) as QTYSUM,i.SKU 
    FROM Database2..Table2 i  
    WHERE i.LOCATION in ('Location1','Location2') 
    GROUP BY i.SKU) o on o.SKU=p.SKU
    where o.QTYSUM>0
```

I am using **ASP.net Core** web application with the **.net Core Framework**. I already have both `dbContext` declared and able to individually query both tables separately. I just can't figure out how to get the result of the join and keep getting **Argument Null Exception** every time I try.

I have made several attempts and can't get it to work.

**Update with 1 of my trys to accomplish this**

```
from p in _DB1context.Table1
join i in
     (from i in _DB2context.Table2
     where i.Location == "Location1" || i.Location == "Location2"
     group i by i.SKU into mygroup
     select new { 
           SKU = mygroup.First().SKU, 
           QtySum = mygroup.Sum(y => y.Qty) }
) on p.SKU equals i.SKU
where i.QtySum > 0
select new {
             pgroup = p,
             SKU= p.SKU,
             QtySum= i.QtySum
            };
```

I get the error as soon as I run a ToList on this, I know I can solve this by creating a stored procedure that does my SQL and just running _context.table1.FromSql("Exec my_Stored_Procedure") but I really want to learn LINQ, once I know where I am wrong it will help me understand this better.
I also did several attempts using _DB1context.Table1.Join(...).Where(...).Select(...) with the same result.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Correction, apparently SO has turned into your code writing service.

Comment: What error do you get now?  One thing I can see is you might use `SKU = mygroup.Key` instead of `SKU = mygroup.First().SKU`.  I would note that EF will not translate a join across contexts into a SQL query that references multiple databases.  For that you'll need a stored procedure (or pass a SQL query directly).

Comment: @DStanley, that is all I needed to know, since it cannot translate the join across context I will just use the Stored procedure I already created for this. Thanks. 
I tried Changing to mygroup.Key and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0)

They give an example for an inner join like so:

```
var innerJoinQuery =
                from category in categories
                join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
                select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name }; //produces flat sequence
```

Comment: If you look at the query closer you'll notice that joining is performed on different databases.

Comment: I have never tried it, but since you prefix the table you are querying with the dbContext, you _should_ be able to use multiple databases in your query.  If not then return the results from each database and join the result sets in C# code.